# displaying html form inputs that gets submitted to the browser?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic html form with textarea input and a submit button. I want to make it so that everything in the textarea gets submitted to the database and retrieved to be posted on the homepage of my website. An example would be the structure of stackoverflow, after posting this question it gets displayed on the homepage alongside other questions submitted in the past. I am using php and mysql. Please give me some direction and hopefully examples to how I can go about this. Thanks

Comment: basic skills => google is your friend

Comment: do u mean after submitting data , you want to fetch immediately from Browser ? Do u mean just SELECT operation?

Comment: I mean after submitting data i want to fetch it and display in the browser immediately thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <form action='index.php' method='post'>
  <textarea name='data' rows='2' cols='20'></textarea>
   <input type='submit' name='submit' value='store'/>
 </form>
```

To Store In database:

```
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
     mysql_select_db('database_name',$con);
  $data = $_POST['data'];
  mysql_query("insert into table_name values ('$data')");
 mysql_close($con)
  {
 ?>
```

To Display in Home Page :

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
     mysql_select_db('database_name',$con);
   $q = mysql_query("select * from table_name");

    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q))
  {
echo $r['data'];
  }
```

Although this is the simplest and most oldest method but yet it can help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I have a problem though then the echo$r['data'] is only printing the first line on my sql table. How to I output my entire questions on the database?

Answer (score 0):

On The Form where textarea and submit button is present, just on click of submit, add the action where you can insert a query for inserting a record into the database. 
And for your home page where you have to show the post . just add select query for posts And display all the posts according to your requirement.